# Why do we get rid of the minus sign when minimizing the cost function of logistic regression?

Tags: optimization, logistic-regression

I don't understand why do we get rid of the minus sign when we want to compute the cost function on N examples in logistic regression. I know that if we minimize something negative we can go far beyond hell, but that's all what I guess. I know it seems seimple but I can't wrap my head on it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to maximize likelihood. That is equivalent to minimizing the negative of likelihood.